# Swift_Attachment - how to get path of the attachment file

Tags: laravel-5.5, swiftmailer

Using the [Swift_Attachment API](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/class-Swift_Attachment.html) I can get the file name `getFilename()` but I can't find a way to get the full path of the file.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and [this email_log library](https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log) but need to modify it so the files are not stored in the database.

I've reached the attachments using `Swift_Message->getChildren()` and inside of it there is

```
-body: Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream { 
  ...
  -path: "/root/path/to/my/file"
  ...
}
```

If I could get the `-body` as a `Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream` instance then I could use the `getPath()` from [here](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/class-Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream.html) but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to store the file from the attachment and not from the path as I couldn't find a way to extract the path.

```
    $messageId = strtok($message->getId(), '@');
    foreach ($message->getChildren() as $child) {
        $attachmentPath = 'email_log_attachments/' . $messageId . '/' . $child->getFilename();
        Storage::put($attachmentPath,$child->getBody());
    }
```